# How to access a file in Struts2?

Tags: xml, path, struts

I like to put an XML file in '/src' directory then access the file in my classes.

I tried the following paths but didn't work.

```
new File("/src/myxml.xml");
new File("src/myxml.xml");
new File("myxml.xml");
```

How do I access the file?

Edited:

1. I'm running a tomcat 7 in Eclipse to run my struts2
2. I've made a class in /src/com.test.test.classes
3. I've uploaded an xml file called myxml.xml in /src

in one of my classes in /src/com.test.test.classes/, How do I access the XML file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say how you're running the program, which makes it substantially more difficult to be helpful. Here's a bunch of Q & A & Suggestions, any of which will solve the problem, depending on what the problem actually is.

- What's the working directory when you run it/what's the complete directory structure?
- Can you just provide a full path or directory argument so you never have to worry about it?
- What if you put the file on the classpath and access it as a resource?

Comment: Put it on your classpath and access it as a resource, our use getRealPath (I think) to get its part relative to the web server root.